# what could be an easiest way of parsing headers and body php

Tags: php, regex

hi guys i below is what i receive from a curl response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Account-Object-Count: 4
X-Account-Bytes-Used: 3072798
X-Account-Container-Count: 3
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2012 04:07:33 GMT

a1
abc
testing
```

i found a good function which parses the headers and i can grab the key value pairs in headers not a problem the problem i have is how to grab the names in the body 
a1 
abc
testing

i think may be regex can do the best job but do not know if regex is the best approach or is there any other function which can return headers separete and body separate.

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

**Updates**
Now i am getting the response as

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Account-Object-Count: 4
X-Account-Bytes-Used: 3072798
X-Account-Container-Count: 3
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 115
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2012 04:47:36 GMT

[{"name":"a1","count":0,"bytes":0},{"name":"abc","count":0,"bytes":0},{"name":"testing","count":4,"bytes":3072798}]
```

so the names are in json

Comment: HTTP headers are always separated from the body by a blank line. That's part of the HTTP spec and should always be true (if it's not, then you can just say that it's not http).

Comment: and how do you detect a blank line using php

Comment: depends on how you're parseing the response. if you're going line-by-line, then when you hit a blank line, you're done with headers and have reached the body. Otherwise look for `\n\n` and split/separate on that.

Comment: Re update: so `json_decode` the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it should be as simple as:

```
list($headers, $body) = explode("\n\n", $response);
$bodyValues = explode("\n", $body);
```

Comment: $headers and $body prints value 1 and nothing else

Comment: The line endings may depend on your OS. Try `\r\n` instead of `\n`. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/RKkPh2. Otherwise, what exactly do you mean by "prints 1"?

Comment: Thanks a lot champ. wish you happy life. .. awesome solution two lines of code only...GOOD ON YA.

Comment: Late comment but this answer assumes that headers are present in the response.